# Incrementing using iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I just started using iterators a few days ago. And while I do get what the basic idea is, I need help clearing something up.

I'm learning c++ from a book and at the end of the chapter about iterator there's a little assignment that goes like this:

"Assuming that "scores" is a vector that holds elements of type int, what's wrong with the following code snippet (meant to increment each element)?

```
vector<int>::iterator iter;

for(iter =scores.begin(); iter !=scores.end(); iter++)
{
    iter++;
}
```

now, it's obvious the iterator iter is already getting incremented by the for loop even without the code inside the loop. so I thought I should just do this do increment the values of the vector that the iterator was referencing.

```
for(iter =scores.begin(); iter !=scores.end(); iter++)
{
    *iter++;
}
```

But that returned an error too. So it got me thinking... is it even possible to increment values using an iterator ? Or is an iterator just an object used to, well, iterate through objects in a container and reference them ? Without being able to actually modify their value ?

Comment: Using parenthesis should fix that: `(*iter)++;`. Lookup operator precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
for(iter =scores.begin(); iter !=scores.end(); iter++)
{
    (*iter)++;
}
```

In C++ operators have different precedences, see [here for a table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Postfix increment is performed before the de-reference.